A rare usage of も — or a mistake?
Another question about Duolingo content (that, as we all know, is not to be trusted too much): in one of the "radio-show" episodes (Section 2, Unit 23), the monologue of the "caller" goes like this (I am copying it exactly, phrase by phrase while re-listening to it as I write this; as there are no subtitles or script provided, I took the liberty of rendering the words into specific kana/kanji as I preferred):

こんにちは。ケンです。私はバスを運転します。仕事のあと、バスを洗います。 同僚はとても優しいです。週末には、会社のジムでよく運動します。姉も翻訳家です。私達はとても忙しいですが、幸せです。

Clearly, the monologue is for beginners, and I'm only listening to those because I've recently bought a new phone, and these "radio shows" only became available to me now (I guess these are just not shown on older phones)
Still, this usage of も seems a mistake (possibly a deliberate one to confuse the listener and make them rely on the overall context of Ken having said before that he is a bus driver and not a translator, i.e., maybe it's an exercise in "correcting the speaker's mistakes based on context", though I have never encountered that in any Japanese learning materials — and even in English learning materials, I have trouble remembering ever encountering anything like that, though, admittedly, it could be a good type of exercise for more advanced learners). Or is it a rare usage, e.g., like the one described here and here?

It seems like a mistake. Duolingo is generally more likely to contain incorrect examples than published books.

Just for slim possibility, there might have been a conversation that Ken has something to do with a foreign language. Or, a person might have asked Ken if the siblings have both busy jobs. Without such contexts, the 'も' sounds strange, indeed.

@norio, strangely, all the males in this "radio exercises" are called "Ken", with all the females called "Hana" (I guess it's for simplicity so that the listener is not distracted by all the possible different names). Still, the exercises do not seem connected to each other with plotlines that would run across different "episodes"

@YusukeMatsubara, I am more inclined to think so now since over these several days, I've encountered a few more strange "radio exercises" there. Among those is the one in Section 3, Unit 7, where there is this sentence: 2月にはスキーをします。寒くない日には夜にスノボ楽しみます。The question is then "What does Ken do in February?"  with the options "Skiing" and "Snowboarding". From the context, snowboarding is also correct since no new time boundaries have been set, only that he goes snowboarding in the evening.

Also, the omission of を before 楽しみます seems strange (yet possible in casual speech I suppose; or maybe it's because of the "o" sound at the end of スノボ that it's not really that well articulated as a separate mora, so ボを becomes just ボー and even ボ in real speech)

@Vladimir Then, that 'も' was likely a mistake. About skiing and snow boarding, I would interpret the sentences as: in February, he goes skiing typically in the day time, and on warmer days he extends the play time into the evenings and switch to snowboarding. The presentation of factual points is very sparse, but there are some people speak in that way. I agree with your comment about omission of 'を'.

I see. So, 寒くない日 here can mean both "warmer days [in February]" — and "warmer days [than in February, i.e., probably in March]". I interpreted it as the former, and the Duolingo team meant the latter. Thank you for all the input
